# python3 decorator method inherited from child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

```
def after_finish(func):

    def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('after finish!')
        return ret

    return _decorator

class AbstractTask:
    @after_finish
    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class ConcreteTask1(AbstractTask):
    def run(self):
        # do concrete task here
        return 0
```

as the code shown above, I have an abstract `AbstractTask` type, and several child class, I would like to put the `after_finish` decorator to the `run` method, which is a general behavior that apply to all sub classes. How can I achieve this purpose by only put the decorator once? Or is there any other approaches that do the same thing, within python3 syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a second method to have

- the public one that you call : `run`
- the private one that you override : `_run`

the use of `abstractmethod` can help your IDE to warn you if you forgot to implement the method

```
from abc import abstractmethod

def after_finish(func):
    def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('after finish!')
        return ret
    return _decorator

class AbstractTask:
    @after_finish
    def run(self):
        self._run()

    @abstractmethod
    def _run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class ConcreteTask1(AbstractTask):
    def _run(self):
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = ConcreteTask1()
    c.run()
```